# unresolved external error in templates c++

Tags: c++

I am getting the following unresolved external error in my C++ code:

*Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup*

*Error  2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals*

I have an abstract parent class and a derived class that implements all the functions. However, due to some strange reasons I am getting this error. If I edit this code without templates, it runs fine. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

template <class E>
class List{

public:

List(){};
virtual ~List(){};
virtual void insert(const E& it) = 0;

};

template<class E>
class Alist : public List<E>{

private:

int maxSize;
int listSize;
int curr;
int biggest;
E* listArray;

public:

Alist(){
    maxSize = 50;
    listSize = 0;
    biggest = 0;
    curr = 0;
    listArray = new E[maxSize];
}

~Alist(){
    delete[] listArray;
}

void insert(const E& it){
    if (curr <0 || curr >= maxSize){
        cout << "The value is out of bounds.";
        return;
    }

    for (int i = listSize; i >= curr; i--){
        listArray[i] = listArray[i + 1];
    }

    if (curr > biggest)
        biggest = curr;

    listArray[curr] = it;
    listSize++;
}


};

template <class E>

int main(){


Alist<int> A();


_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the exact error and try to localized the problem.

Comment: `main` cannot be a template

Comment: @alkino, I have edited the code and included the exact errors. Thanks for your time

Comment: got it, thanks! I was repeating the template definition before main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't declare `main` as a function template:

   ```
   template <class E>
   int main(){
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   int main(){
   ```
2. The below code:

   ```
   Alist<int> A();
   ```

   is a declaration of a function taking no parameters and returning `Alist<int>`, instead it should be:

   ```
   Alist<int> A{}; //c++11
   ```

   or:

   ```
   Alist<int> A;
   ```
3. Don't use `<conio.h>` header, it is not a standard one.
4. Don't put anyhing between `[]` brackets in a `delete` statement:

   ```
   delete[curr] listArray;
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   delete[] listArray;
   ```

[Working demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9161f2008a1db6aa)

Comment: Regarding fourth point, so suppose I want to delete a single element in the array, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

main function should not be template. Compiler is looking for a non-template main function as entry point.

Just remove `template <class E>` before `main` declaration. It does not make sense here.

If you really want a template main function, you should call it from a non-template one:

```
namespace my {
    template <class E>
    int main(){
        Alist<E> A;
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    return my::main<int>();
}
```

But I don't see the point in doing that.

Comment: Yep, I removed the template definition before main and it's working now

Comment: Re my edit: The global namespace `main` function can't be a template, even if there is a non-template one.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: Thanks ;-). But I could not understand where the "most vexing parse" applies here :-(

Comment: @jpo38: now point 2 in [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25833973/464581).

Comment: OK. Thanks again. Got this error many times and never really understood why compiler wanted me to remove the extra ()....I learn something today. Thanks!